# Can Parallels Desktop on Mac utilize additional video RAM installed in the 'host'?

Tags: macos, graphics-card, virtual-machine, virtualization, parallels

Wondering if Parallels Desktop running can utilize additional video RAM installed on the host (MacBook) for the virtual machines?

In other words if it's worth buying a MacBook pro with more video RAM (4GB instead of 2GB) purely from the perspective of Parallels desktop?

Comment: No, it won't. You need different virtualization solutions and additional hardware in order to use the graphics card/chip (and VRAM) at its full potential in a VM.

Comment: 'Is it worth it?... only you can decide that. Parallels has a 2GB graphics RAM maximum - but if that would still allow you 2GB 'spare' for the Mac, then that's a consideration.